# How to make SubDirectories?

Tags: subdomain

I have my server on WAMP, and domain under domain.com. How do you make sub directories on your website? (as in website.com/subdirectory) All i could get is the ugly (ipaddress)/(random folder)/asdf.html. I am new to website coding so explain it simply, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st mistake you made is to have a WAMP server instead of a LAMP one (this is just my humble opinion).
Beside this, making a folder should be almost the same on both environment, you have two choices:

- Download an FTP client like FileZilla, use it to access to your
  server main directory and create a new subdirectory. (The webhoster
  should have provided you the FTP access credentials)
- If you have
  something like cPanel on your WAMP environment (which I doubt) you
  could use the Server File Manager provided by cPanel to create a
  subdirectory. Anyway even with other control panels like Plesk I think you can do it.

Comment: Yeah I agree Linux would be better for these purposes... But its not my computer its my friends :(

Comment: Your computer could be Window, but the server can be Linux. cPanel with Linux makes you able to manage your server by simply using your browser from a Windows machine or even a Mac.